# Deploy express with nodemon using gitlab cicd

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, nodemon

I'm trying to deploy my `express` `API` on `AWS` using a gitlab pipeline. Since it is a development server, the server is managed through `nodemon`.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:15 AS base

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm i

FROM base AS production

RUN yarn build
```

this is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: base
      args:
        PORT: ${PORT}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:${PORT}
    command: yarn start:dev
```

and this is the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: node:latest

stages:
  - deploy-dev
  - start-dev

deploy_dev:
  stage: deploy-dev
  image: node
  before_script:
    - echo " Starting deployment [development mode]..."
    - 'which ssh-agent || (apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y)'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$KEY_DEV" > "$(pwd)/key.pem"
    - chmod 400 $(pwd)/key.pem
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get -y install rsync
  script:
    - ssh -T -i $(pwd)/key.pem user@$DEV
    - rsync -zvhr -auv --exclude 'node_modules' -e "ssh -T -i $(pwd)/key.pem" ./auth user@$DEV:/home/user/services
    - echo " Deployment completed..."
    - echo " Starting auth services..."
    - ssh -T -i $(pwd)/key.pem user@$DEV "cd ./services/auth/; docker-compose --env-file ./config/.development.env down; docker-compose --env-file ./config/.development.env up --build;"
  only: ['dev']
```

In general it works but the problem is that once the container is started the pipleline always remains running. How can I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the docker compose in detached mode (`docker-compose up --detach`).
This will cause the containers to run in the background (non-blocking call).
More info can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).